# Delete a line in multiple files that contain a string in Linux

Tags: linux, sed, grep, exec

I am moving some of my pages from `8859` to `UTF` so I just included the `UTF` in my file that is included on most pages. I am trying to erase the line with the `charset` definition from pages with that include.

`find . -type f -exec grep -lr 'headIncluded' {} + -exec sed -i '/meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text\/html; charset/d' {} \;`

I thought this one should work, but I noticed that it erased the line in a few pages where `headIncluded` was not present. Any suggestions to what is wrong with this command?

Comment: can you the input sample?

Comment: The final sed command will take no account of the output of grep only the output of find. The grep command is in effect redundant and so the sed command will be performed on every file returned from find not just those with "headIncluded" within the file

Comment: @RamanSailopal so basically it erases that line in every found file using `find . -type f`. Can you suggest an alternative that would work?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you mean a sample of one of the pages? They are long so it won't be the best idea. They are typical `jsp` pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try:

```
grep -lr "headIncluded" /pathtodirectory/* | xargs sed -i '/meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text\/html; charset/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `+` to terminate the `-exec`, the command is run with multiple files.  If any of those files contain the string, the grep will succeed.  Also, from the documentation "this variant of -exec always returns true", so the return value of `grep` is irrelevant.